# Detect " in a JSON-String and escape it at certain position

Tags: java, json

I receive a string which contains a JSON object, unfortunately one of the values in that JSON-String looks like this:

```
{
    "name":"Content-Type",
    "value":"multipart/alternative; boundary="=-SITt2U5w3MJ1Y3RihaWzxw==""
}
```

As you can see the value of this JSON Object contains two `"` signs which need to be escaped so the outcome looks like this:

```
{
    "name":"Content-Type",
    "value":"multipart/alternative; boundary=/"=-SITt2U5w3MJ1Y3RihaWzxw==/""
}
```

Then the parsing into a JAVA Pojo works. Unforunately I can't detect it, the object above is one of many which come in an array. I know I could detect 'boundary' as a key word and escape the next two `"`-signs, I tried to get it working with regular expressions, but had no success doing so.

What could I do here?

Comment: I would try to tackle the problem at the source. What you are getting is invalid JSON and thus most likely violates the contract of your API. You _could_ try to use a regex that matches on `boundary=...` but can you be sure that there will always be exactly 2 double quotes that need to be escaped and that this only happens with "boundary"?

Comment: / is not an escape character, you probably meant \. And Thomas is right, there is no point in trying to solve this problem on your end, get whoever is responsible for this so-called API to fix it so it emits valid JSON.

Comment: You're right, the escaped should be \" of course. Unortunately I have no possibility to change the source since its an Amazon AWS API. I use the Java SDK, it emits this faulty JSON.

Comment: @TobiasKuess Then you should probably replace the JSON serializer/deserializer with a different one.

Comment: I'm using Gson of google. The only thing that would help me would be a regex which detects 'boundary=' and the next '=' after that so I can replace it in the string before parsing the JSON.

Comment: `I receive a string which contains a JSON object` - you're not. This is not a valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is to escape the double quotes using regex, the below snippet can help.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "{\n" +
                "    \"name\":\"Content-Type\",\n" +
                "    \"value\":\"multipart/alternative; boundary=\"=-SITt2U5w3MJ1Y3RihaWzxw==\"\"\n" +
                "}";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("boundary=\"([^\"]*?)\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("boundary=\\\\\"" + matcher.group(1) + "\\\\\""));
        }
    }
```

It produces the below output:

```
{
    "name":"Content-Type",
    "value":"multipart/alternative; boundary=\"=-SITt2U5w3MJ1Y3RihaWzxw==\""
}
```

---

**Regex pattern:** `boundary="([^]*?)"`

**Explanation:** After `boundary="` possessively match all characters till the next `"`. In replacement using the capture group to include escape characters

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly!